# How to use fonts in external SWF files

Tags: apache-flex

What I would like to do is a flex app, that uses fonts that are available in external swf.
What I have succeded so far is:

- to create a AS class hat holds the embedded font:

  package 
     {
      import flash.display.Sprite;

  ```
  public class _Arial extends Sprite
  {
      [Embed(source='C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/ARIAL.TTF', fontName='_Arial', unicodeRange='U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E')]
      public static var _MyArial:Class;
  }
  ```

  }
- compiled this into a swf with following command: `mxmlc.exe -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true _Arial.as`

When I try to load the font from my flex app, this fails with following error message:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1508: The value specified for argument font is invalid.
    at flash.text::Font$/registerFont()
    at valueObjects::FontLoader/fontLoaded()[C:\Documents and Settings\nutrina\Adobe Flash Builder 4\flex_pdf\src\valueObjects\FontLoader.as:33]
```

This is the code where I try to load the SWF file:

```
   package 
   {

    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.*;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.core.FontAsset;

    public class FontLoader extends Sprite {

        public function FontLoader(url:String) {
            super();
            loadFont(url);
        }

        private function loadFont(url:String):void {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fontLoaded);
            loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
        }

        private function fontLoaded(event:Event):void {
            var fontList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(Font.enumerateFonts(true));
            var FontLibrary:Class = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("_Arial") as Class;
            trace("FontList: " + fontList)
            trace("FontLibrary: " + FontLibrary)
            trace("FontLibrary._Arial: " + FontLibrary._MyArial)
            Font.registerFont(FontLibrary._MyArial);

            fontList = new ArrayCollection(Font.enumerateFonts(true));
            trace("Font list: " + fontList)
        }
    }
   }
```

The font file is definitely not corrupt because if I put the _Arial class from the code above into the Flex application, the embedding works. So my guess is that probably I missed some compilation options?

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks,
Gerald

Comment: why you want to have the font in an external swf ?

Comment: I need this in an external swf, because in the end there will a number of font files that shall be available in my app. And only a few of them will be used - that shall be configurable at runtime, and will depend on what the user will be doing.

Embedding all the fonts in the app does not really make sense, because the size of that one will grow to much.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with class name conflicts. I wrestled with an external font loading issue for hours. Turns out my font class was called "Main", and so was the application that was trying to load it. The font never got registered correctly.